# Using the same variable in the loops for solving the, "Closures in the loop" issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, closures

In continuation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) question, I tried the following code that uses the same variable in both the loops and I get the desired result. My question is, WHY ?

**So the initial code is:**

```
 var funcs = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
 }

 for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      // this will not give desired output
 }
```

**The outputs this:**

- My value: 3
- My value: 3
- My value: 3

**Whereas, the intended output is:**

- My value: 0
- My value: 1
- My value: 2

**Now, if I use variable 'i' (a global variable) in the second loop as well, the code looks like:**

```
var funcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      // let's create 3 functions
  funcs[i] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
    console.log("My value: " + i); // each should log its value.
  };
}

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i]();                      // this gives desired output
}
```

**I get the intended output**,

- My value: 0
- My value: 1
- My value: 2

**WHY?**

Comment: because `i` is a global in your code

Comment: 3 it's last value for i, when you calling it

Comment: rewrite your code to declare `var i` once, before the for loops - because that is what you are actually doing, the two `var i` are actually the same `i` - it becomes clear

Comment: The whole point of the "closures inside loops" issue is that the inner function prints the *current* value of `i`. If you change the second loop to e.g. `for (var i = 10; i < 13; i++) {` it should become more clear.

Comment: Even if you put `var i` it still global (at least belongs to the scope outside the `for`s). Try wrap each `for` inside a function then you'll get the result of 3 `3`s no matter what variable you use (even `i` itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, if I use variable 'i' (a global variable) in the second loop as
>   well ... I get the intended output ... WHY?

Because when you do the first executing loop:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                      
 }
```

the loop constructing the array has finished and the global variable `i` has the value `3` and therefore `console.log(i)` results in logging `3` to the console for each iteration of the first executing loop. When you do the second executing loop:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  funcs[i]();                      
}
```

you for each iteration of the loop assign a new value to the global variable `i` and it is this new value that the `console.log(i)` will log to the console: 0, 1, 2.

### How do you achieve the desired result in a simple way?

You can use `let` to achieve the desired result in a simple way:

```
"use strict"; // use of let requires strict mode

var funcs = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // just replace var with let here     
  funcs[i] = function() {          
    console.log("My value: " + i); 
  };
 }

 for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                     
 }
```

Now the array will be constructed with functions having access to a local variable, which is assigned the value of `i` at the time of adding the function to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Because the variable `i` is contaminated. In your snippets, The loops write to the same variable `i` and the functions reads it. Note that there is just one variable `i` in your code.

What you really need to get your intended result is called "module pattern", which wraps a function to keep a local copy of the variable in the loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    (function (j) {
        funcs[j] = function() {          // and store them in funcs
            console.log("My value: " + j); // each should log its value.
        };
    })(i);
}
```

You can read [this article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) to get more information about "module pattern".